# What affiliation to put on a research paper as a college student?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, affiliation

I am an undergraduate, and I want to know what to put as an affiliation on a research paper.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Rules for affiliation for student doing unpaid research in his/her free time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/890/rules-for-affiliation-for-student-doing-unpaid-research-in-his-her-free-time)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, if you are a student, your affiliation will be the school / college / university that you attend (or if you have recently changed institutions, the one you attended when you did the work and wrote the paper).