# Affiliation of an Undergraduate Student: Paper Publication

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate student, and I'm working on a (physics) project with one of my supervisors. We hope to complete the project soon and submit it to various journals for publication.

Most journals require the affiliation of the authors. Since I am an undergraduate student, I'm not affiliated with/hired by a university's department, per say. How would I ho about filling in the affiliation section (in my case)? Should I be leaving it blank?

Comment: Also see [Rules for affiliation for student doing unpaid research in his/her free time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/890/rules-for-affiliation-for-student-doing-unpaid-research-in-his-her-free-time)