# What is your affiliation when publishing as a student?

Tags: publications, phd

As a professor/postdoc, when you submit an article to a journal you note your department, school, and city:

> Department of History, Barnett College, Fairfield, New York

But when you are in a PhD program, do you need to explicitly mention it in your address and if so how?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to?

Comment: Also related: [Rules for affiliation for student doing unpaid research in their free time?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/890/17254) (the answers of which aren't restricted to undergraduate students).

Comment: "when you are in a PhD program, do you need to explicitly mention it in your address ...?" No, there is no distinction between a PhD student or a professor as an author. Generally, that simply doesn't matter. Your affiliation should contain the same kind of information as a professor's affiliation, unless the author guide of the journal demands something different.

Comment: @Buffy There is no reason. I want to as long as it is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely appropriate, highly recommended, and possibly mandatory if this is part of your PhD work.

The format you have mentioned should be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an enrolled student can use the university (and the department) as an affiliation. It is probably a good idea to also note that you are a student so that people will realize that the affiliation will change within a few years (or less). So, add "(Doctoral Student)" or similar when possible.

When you use an affiliation you want the institution to be able to verify it if needed.

Comment: I've never seen a note like that, is it common in your fields?