# What to do with research results while being in high school?

Tags: publications, mathematics, repository

I have written a math paper on combinatorics (a generalization of a math olympiad problem) and am looking to get it published. I believe I have discovered something new (although I don't claim it is "important" in the sense of being a breakthrough or anything) and want to get credit for it. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find anyone to endorse me to publish on arxiv, so I'm trying to get it published in another (less popular) repository that doesn't need endorsement.

Any suggestions? Things I have looked at so far:

- academia.edu - apparently this isn't safe enough for protecting your work.
- hal archives ouvertes - I tried searching about this one but there's no information regarding how trustworthy it is, etc.
- github - this seems to be for computer science.
- vixra - looked promising at first considering the "everything gets accepted" rule, but then the downside is that people have started viewing it as an arxiv for crackpots, so it doesn't seem like a good idea to publish there, but this being my first paper I'm not so sure.

I would love to hear your thoughts on this and any advice you can give.

Note: I'm not prepared to send my paper to any journals so that is out of the question at the moment.

Comment: I assume you don't have any academic affiliations?

Comment: Relevant: 1. [Publishing amateur research](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/941/), 2. [Is it possible to publish a research paper as an independent undergraduate author?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/) and 3. [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18491/).

Comment: @user92570 You should ask your teachers whether they have any contacts at university. My high school chemistry teacher, for example, was from Yale, and he put me in touch when I was in high school.

Comment: @user92570 Also, make *absolutely* sure the work you've done hasn't been done before. That means extensively searching relevant journal papers. Springer's LaTeX search engine may help, in some cases. You have written your paper in LaTeX, right? Either way, have a look at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-821-project-laboratory-in-mathematics-spring-2013/ to make sure it's well-written and conforms with general guidelines.

Comment: @user92570 Out of curiosity, what have you done (without going into too much detail) in combinatorics?

Comment: Get a sponsor, submit to [Intel STS](https://student.societyforscience.org/intel-sts) next year?

Comment: Definitely avoid vixra. It was started by crackpots for crackpots; if someone put something reasonable there it would be lost in the noise.

Comment: Tips from http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement: You can find somebody qualified to endorse by clicking on the link "Which of these authors are endorsers?" at the bottom of every abstract. The email addresses of the submitter is on the abstract page at the top of the"Submission history" section. If you do not personally know anyone eligible to endorse, search for recent submissions in your field of interest…a good idea to send eligible endorsers a copy of your proposed submission along with the endorsement request. Don't email large numbers of potential endorsers at once.

Comment: @Matt Reece: I started viXra. It was created for people who have problems submitting to arXiv. Why are you calling me a crackpot? Here is my publication list https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?user=Au-AVHsAAAAJ&hl=en

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, if it is not submission-ready, then it is unlikely that it is arXiv-ready either.

If you put it in another place, you won't get much prestige or recognition, so I would aim at a place accessible to everyone (without login) - your homepage, GitHub or anything (it does not matter). It may be a good place if you want to start discussions.

Second, it is rather unlikely that it's something ground-breaking that everyone would like to steal from you. (But don't get discouraged -  it is certainly possible that it is an *interesting* result!) You would benefit more from discussions than have to lose.

Third, some guidance is needed. Ideally, you can consult it with a friendly teacher, professor or PhD student. If not possible, one way to go is to try some research-level competitions for high school students (e.g. like [First Step to Nobel Prize in Physics](http://www.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/), [European Union For Young Scientists](http://ec.europa.eu/research/eucys/index_en.cfm?pg=home) or something in that line). Even if you don't win anything (those are very though competitions) you might get some feedback. Additionally, <del>even</del> in Poland there are a few local competitions for works in mathematics by high schools students (e.g. [this](http://spinor.edu.pl/sejmik.php) and [that](http://www.deltami.edu.pl/delta/redakcja/konkurs_prac_uczniowskich/)). I am sure in UK there are also some. If you did something in a Math Olympiad, you can try asking organizers if they know such competitions (or someone suitable for mentoring you).

Comment: @user92570 You can ask on fora, but don't take for granted that people will have time read it (hint: make it as readable as possible). If I can ask, what is your country?

Comment: @user92570 Even in Poland there are a few local competitions for works in mathematics by high schools students (e.g. [this](http://spinor.edu.pl/sejmik.php) and [that](http://www.deltami.edu.pl/delta/redakcja/konkurs_prac_uczniowskich/)). I am sure in UK there are also some. Or if you did something in an Math Olympiad, you can try asking organizers if they know such competitions.

Comment: @user92570 Considering how much writing in mathematics has changed since Euler's time, I'd consider modelling your paper after modern standards. See the OCW course I linked in the comments.

Comment: @Piotr: "Even in Poland" is a strange thing to say when it comes to mathematics: Poland has a famously strong mathematical community.  (One might as well say, "Even in Hungary we have our little problem-solving contests"...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Good point (BTW: IPhO was started by Poland). But as of the present day, I believe that UK has stronger mathematical community (though, I am not aware if it implies more opportunities for high school students).

Answer (score 11):

I am actually just a few steps ahead of your shoes, so I'll tell you what I'm doing, that I think might help you as well.

In high-school I also found something interesting in mathematics. I've been developing it for a year now, so now that I'm in college I tried taking it to professors. Surprisingly, none of them had much interest in primality testing. After doing a little research of my own and looking publications similar to what I am working on, I found a few journals that have published similar work to mine. Looking at the requirements of the journal submission, I found their TeX format and I am now currently working to format my work in TeX before I submit my work to a Journal.

So my advice, although I can't relate to success yet, would be if the work you are doing is relevant enough (that it might have a use for someone else), then:

1. Turn it into TeX if you haven't yet
2. Make sure your work has a good "story" (Explain the work and its relevance  thoroughly)
3. Make sure grammar and spelling are flawless
4. Find a couple Journals you could possibly submit it to, and pick the top one (Look at other's work and papers, and remember, typically you can only submit to one journal simultaneously)
5. Format and submit

I've found that the proof itself is less than half the work. And its taken me a couple months to were I'm at (near-finishing an semi-important generalization and a new algorithm in publication format). So just keep working on it, and give it effort. Best of Luck!

Comment: Points 1-3 are great (especially LaTeX, not necessary TeX). For 4-5 it is a bit more complicated. As of now it is "4. 5. ??? PROFIT!". In reality, these are hard steps for publishing for the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure about 4. I've found a couple Journals very easily. Like I said, just looking for similar publications I've found 3 or 4. Unless the work being done is extremely original, then there searching for publications in the area of interest should be no problem. The only thing I might not be able to relate to is the success of submitting to a Journal, which, I'll have to find out myself.