# Can a high school student involved in a college credit program get an arXiv endorsement?

Tags: mathematics, arxiv

I'm 16, homeschooled, and I am taking [dual credit at LoneStar](http://www.lonestar.edu/dualcredit.htm). If I wanted to write a paper, unlikely, but I've toyed with the idea, would I be able to get a suitable endorsement from a mathematics teacher at LoneStar? I was considering submitting on arXiv.

My guess would be no, but I don't know much about how this works, so I'd be interested to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endorsement is *not* a service offered by a college, like academic advisement or career placement. Endorsement is an indication that the endorser knows you and believes you are not a crank, or has read your paper and believes it is a reasonably appropriate paper. It's not like just by having a connection to the college, you could automatically be eligible for an endorsement from a professor there.

A program through which high school students can earn college credit does not necessarily give its students increased access to mathematics faculty. So this "connection" may or may not be of use to you in gaining an endorsement. Instead, I recommend reading [What to do with research results while being in high school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40649/what-to-do-with-research-results-while-being-in-high-school) and [How to find an arXiv endorser](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20186/how-to-find-an-arxiv-endorser) for suggestions on what to do with your paper, should you choose to write one. The latter explains how to find names of people who are eligible to endorse in a given area. (There may or may not be anyone in the college you are connected to who is eligible in your area.)

Comment: No, I meant could someone from the college faculty be eligible to endorse me? I'd know them, and they might actually help me out.

Comment: @Zach the question I linked, "How to find an arXiv endorser" explains how to find names of people who are eligible to endorse papers in a given area.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yea that means I probably couldn't, LoneStar is a community college. Who knows though, I might get lucky ;)

Comment: @Zach some community college professors do active research. Alternatively, they may be able to make a connection for you to someone who is an active researcher in your area. Can't hurt to ask.