# What to put in "affiliation" field when submitting paper without affiliation?

Tags: publications, independent-researcher, affiliation

Recently my paper is reviewed (by a professor from independent third party) and accepted by a journal. But, my employer allows me to publish this paper only without its name there.

Publishing house is expecting affiliation for each author, i.e. I can not leave affiliation as blank.

What should I write as the affiliation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As noted by [@mankoff in a comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers#comment17608_3010) on [Does one need to be affiliated with a university to publish papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers), you can use "Independent Scholar":

> Here is a recent paper published by someone affiliated as "Independent Scholar": [dx.doi.org/10.1175/BAMS-D-12-00171.1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1175/BAMS-D-12-00171.1)

Comment: Or "Independent Researcher" or "Unaffiliated" or "None". Different online systems might filter differently.

Answer (score 9):

For completeness’ sake, I mention that another option would be to give your private address as an affiliation.
[Here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(89)90081-4) is an example for this. [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5520.pdf) is another one (affiliations are at the end of the paper)¹. [This one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01596) only lists the city and country part of the address².

---

¹ Credits to [Jessica B](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/20036/jessica-b) for pointing this one out.
² Credits to [Cheersmate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/101067/cheersmate) for pointing this one out.

Comment: @cheersmate: Thanks. I added it to my answer.