# How should an independent researcher introduce him/herself in his/her to be submitted articles?

Tags: paper-submission, independent-researcher, affiliation, non-academic-staff

As we all know, all academic professors or students who want to submit an article (research or review) to a journal should write their affiliations (their institute name and job there) on the first page of the article.

All of the articles I have read till now were from academic authors and I haven't met a single article from an independent researcher yet.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/what-to-put-in-affiliation-field-when-submitting-paper-without-affiliation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked questions provide good answers ("Unaffiliated Scholar" / "Independent Scholar"), but another question might be what do you hope to accomplish with your paper?

Are you trying to simply make a contribution to the academic literature? In this case, Unaffiliated Scholar might be the best approach. Are you interested in establishing your bona fides for a corporate career or consulting business? In this case, I have seen plenty of independent researchers publish with their personal consulting company as their affiliation. The paper then presumably adds to the academic literature while providing a track record to use in advertising for future consulting gigs. In this case you may need to incorporate yourself, which is beyond the scope of Academia SE.