# Publishing with a master's degree and no academic affiliation?

Tags: publications, masters, independent-researcher

Currently I am finishing a master's degree in linguistics. I was accepted for a Ph.D at my university, but I decided not to do it in the end. I love my research and my field, but I don't see myself as a professor and I'm not sure a purely academic career is for me. Furthermore, my husband and I would suffer from the 'two body problem' if I got my Ph.D since he already graduated from his Ph.D program, and that is a situation I want to avoid. I am considering doing a clinical master's in SLP to apply my background in linguistics and biology in a clinical rather than purely academic setting.
For the time being I will be taking a year off, but I am wondering about the idea of 'independent researchers'. If I continued with my research (which I can do from my computer using open access corpora and other corpora I have access to) could I publish/present my findings? If I became an SLP could I continue to publish even though I wouldn't have a Ph.D?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could take a look at the answers to this question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3010/358. You might also find that a professional doctorate would meet your needs (there are various names for these). Good luck!