# How can I enter name as author(even after work)in a govt level research without affiliation with an institution?

Tags: authorship, independent-researcher, affiliation

This question is particularly aimed to target researchers with many years experience in this field.I have done bachelors in Bioinformatics and got an unofficial/voluntary opportunity to work with United nations on a research via local government organization.Although I would be doing the work myself and even document the paper but my superviser says that as I am not affiliated with any institution right now so I cant be put into authors section.But I have heard people work and write papers even after graduation.I want to know how is that done and what am I supposed to write in affiliation part if I want to get the research published.please tell the process in detail.Also, is it possible if I can be associated with thay phd scholar or something without being affiliated with institution?Any information regarding it will be helpful with details please.

Comment: @ff524 It seems http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers is closer than the question you linked (which incidentally you linked in your answer to the question you linked).

Comment: @PVAL There are multiple questions in this post. I chose a duplicate of the "what am I supposed to write in affiliation part if I want to get the research published" part, but the question you link is also useful - thanks for digging it up.