# Would this work be publishable in a journal of physical philosophy?

Tags: journals, physics, philosophy

### Background

So I can derive the relative maxwell distribution (selecting 2 random particles what is the probability they have a particular relative velocity) from relative variables (relative position, relative momentum, etc). My friends have told me since in some sense a rederivation of the Maxwell distribution it probably isn't publishable in a physics journal.

Given how this plays a role in the discussion of [Leibniz's idea against absolutes](https://iep.utm.edu/leib-met/#SH7a)
I was wondering if perhaps this could be published in a physical philosophy journal? (Also I'm not sure how me not being currently in academia will affect things).

### Question

Is this manuscript publishable in a journal of physical philosophy? (Any recommendations will help)

Comment: This site is not the right place to evaluate the publishability of individual works because this requires subject knowledge and a strong familiarity with your work. However, please have a look on the [tag:independent-researcher] tag regarding on how to proceed with publishing, in particular [When submitting a research paper as an independent researcher, is it advisable to have a professor look at it first?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11250/7734). In short: You probably want to find some expert on the field to assess publishability and mentor you along the publishing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this? Unlikely. You would have to ground it in the philosophy of physics and explain why you are doing something that is new and why it is relevant to a wider discussion in the history and philosophy of science. Both Maxwell and Leibniz are subjects of VERY active, long-term and rigorous scholarship.  You would need to do considerable background reading to understand where your work fitted into the wider picture of contemporary scholarship, what problem you were trying to address, and why it was (genuinely) new compared to all the existing papers out there.